# How to import API definition from .jar without embedding .jar on compliation?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I'm building a module-based *demo* project in Java. The aim is to build a super small Core Application that will only connect modules between them. Modules, once connected, will communicate directly through APIs sepecific to every module.

Every module, because it'll be developped independently, will have to be its own jar, and will be able to be compiled on its own and be integrated in the Core App by simply putting the .jar of the module into a specific folder. The Core App will then load these modules (at startup or runtime if possible) using the `ServiceLoader` API.

All the projects will use Maven, and be developped in Eclipse.

Every module will implement an IModule interface defining basic methods to connect modules (simply share references of instanciated modules between them), and this interface is defined in its own `.jar`.

This design pattern requires that some modules (let's say Module1) are aware of the API of the others with which they will communicate (Module2).

**How can I make Module1 aware of the API of Module2 without compiling them together?** I'm currently thinking adding the `Module2.jar` to the Build Path of Module1, but I'm not sure if this will integrate the whole `Module2.jar` in the `Module1.jar` during the compilation. And if once loaded, both modules will be able to communicate.

And **Can I do these things in a "Maven-ess" way ?**

Keep in mind that I'm far (*far*) from being an Java expert and that this app will be a "demo" app. If the development of this demo app goes well (and thus I'd prove that this pattern is suitable for my needs), I might implement it in a real world application. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to deal with module dependency is to decouple interface (API) from its implementation.

Is is called [Dependency inversion principle (DI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and is one of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles.

Applied to your situation that would turn into:

- Have two jar (and two maven submodules) for **each** of your modules.

  > Ex: `module1-api.jar`, `module1-impl.jar`, `module2-api.jar` and `module2-impl.jar`
- Make each implementation depend on its API.

  > Ex: `module1-impl.jar` will depend on `module1-api.jar`
- Make each requiring module depend on the API of its dependency

  > Ex: `module1-impl.jar` will depend on `module2-api.jar`

The most important part of it is that the implementations don't depend on each other: `module1-impl.jar` doesn't need to depend on `module2-impl.jar`.

It enables also to have multiple implementations of the same interface and make it possible for requiring modules to "switch" from one implementation to another easily.

API should contain only Java interfaces and DTO (POJO used to exchange data only).

The downside is that API (`*-api.jar`) are required at compile time by the requiring implementations.

#### Maven considerations

You can have all your modules defined in a [multi-module maven project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html).

As an example, you could use the following maven directory configuration:

```
parent               (main multi-module parent, type:pom)
 |- core-application (type:jar)
 |- module1-api      (type:jar)
 |- module1-impl     (type:jar)
 |- module2-api      (type:jar)
 \- module2-imp      (type:jar)
```

Or also:

```
parent               (main multi-module parent, type:pom)
 |- core-application (type:jar)
 |- module1          (multi-module module1 parent, type:pom)
 |   |- module1-api  (type:jar)
 |   \- module1-impl (type:jar)
 \- module2          (multi-module module2 parent, type:pom)
     |- module2-api  (type:jar)
     \- module2-imp  (type:jar
```

**EDIT:**

If you need a fine control of the modules lifecycle (start/stop), you may be more interested in [OSGi](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi)

Comment: OK. That seems to complexify a bit my plans, but surely is cleaner. I guess there is no other way to build such a module based application? For instance by making the Core App a bit more involved in the inter-modules communication ? I'm quite a newbie in software architecture and this is my first actual try at it, so I might have missed some docs / patterns...

Comment: I don't really need a "precise" control. My idea is just to implement a 3 layer application, with multiple modules by layer, and be as clean as possible knowing that I'll be working on it with several people handling a module each.

Comment: The advantage of api and impl is that the api jar will change less. So with version control of maven be more stable.

Comment: You could also have a single "communication" interface implemented by all of your modules. Then, your modules would only need to depend on this  "communication" interface. It really depends on what needs to exchanged between the modules. BTW, what I described in the answer is the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) that is one of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles.

Comment: @Rems FYI, we do this a lot at my work, and even if there is often only one impl by API, it is valuable, because it reduces the complexity of links between the modules, that's the primary goal of DI

Comment: @superbob Good to know ! So I guess you have a central custom Maven repository and you use it to access all the JAR's ? BTW, thank you very much, I'm getting ahead of my initial post here.

Comment: @Rems A private custom repository is not required to do it. You can achieve this with a [multi-module maven project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) That's what we often do at my work. A final word: I used DI acronym for dependency inversion. It is different from dependency injection (that is also called DI), see this [link](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/22/dependency-injection-is-not-the-same-as-the-dependency-inversion-principle/) for some considerations about that

Comment: @superbob I knew about Dependency Injection (as I've work on some PHP Object Frameworks before which make an extensive use of it a.k.a. Symfony2). And I will check Dependency Inversion as soon as I'm done doing something unrelated. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rems, I added maven considerations to my answer. I can tell by experience that DI and DI are true allies for the Java world also :)

Comment: @superbob Nice man! I was about to get started on the multi module configuration.
Haha I'm sure DI&DI would work ! But this project will also be coded partly by people whom I'm not sure of their developping skills, so I don't want to introduce too much advanced pattern such as DInjection... Cause it might not be used correctly by everyone, and would end up being a mess.